# Center the page number in a footer using PyPDF

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm using PyPDF to create a formatted report. I want the page number (e.g. Page 1 of 3) to be centered in the footer, pretty much exactly how the PyPDF tutorial shows. [Here's the tutorial I'm referencing.](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/06/05/creating-pdfs-with-pyfpdf-and-python/)

Below is the code I put in the footer method:

```
def footer(self):
    genDateTime = "Report generated on: " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    page = 'Page ' + str(self.page_no()) + '/{nb}'

    self.set_y(-10)
    self.set_font('Arial', '', 9)

    self.cell(0, 5, "Clinical Report: Confidential", 0, 0, 'L')
    self.cell(0, 5, page, 0, 0, 'C')
    self.cell(0, 5, genDateTime, 0, 0, 'R')
```

Here is a screenshot of the bottom of the page. As you can see, the Confidential and DateTime labels are showing up as expected, but the Page # label is right justified:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with how you are setting cell width. PyPDF by default places cells sequentially, starting at the far right of the previously placed cell. When you call `self.cell()`, the first argument is width -- by default if width is 0, it makes the width extend to the far right of the page. So when you place `self.cell(0, 5, "Clinical Report: Confidential", 0, 0, 'L')`, that text box is extending all the way to the right of the page. Then when you try to place `self.cell(0, 5, page, 0, 0, 'C')`, it is centering it in the remaining space on that line -- but there is no space left so it just places it at the end. Try giving your first cell some width like this:

```
def footer(self):
    genDateTime = "Report generated on: " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    page = 'Page ' + str(self.page_no()) + '/{nb}'

    self.set_y(-10)
    self.set_font('Arial', '', 9)

    self.cell(5, 5, "Clinical Report: Confidential", 0, 0, 'L')
    self.cell(0, 5, page, 0, 0, 'C')
    self.cell(0, 5, genDateTime, 0, 0, 'R')
```

You might have to make the width greater than 5 to display all your text, but you can play with that.

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks so much. Out of curiosity, why was the right justified time placing correctly if the left justified text took up the whole page width?

Comment: After you placed the first box (which took up the whole width), the centered box and right-justified box both were forced to be jammed into the end of the line. This isn't a problem for something that is right-justified (since it forces it all the way to the right anyway.) Does that make sense?

Comment: @KieranPaddock did you delete your other question where I directed you to PyPDF?

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. And I didn't delete it, I just looked at it and for some reason all the comments/answers are gone, though I didn't touch the post.

Comment: @KieranPaddock Ahh, ok. Looks like a mod deleted my answer -- presumably because it was only a link? That's why I couldn't find it in my history. However, I still think it was a useful question and answer pair so I reposted an answer with a simple demo, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

You Could make your cell the same size as the page so that the

```
self.cell()
```

can center it to that size/orientation